# Sticking Numbers

Tags: pattern, formation-of-numbers, seven-segment

Try to figure out the answers from the 2 patterns below. Find all the 10 digits first. Rotate if necessary.

[image]

A: What is the missing number?     [?]      [10]       [11]       [9]      [11]

[image]

B- What is the missing number?     [?] [ 3]  [ 7]  [ 2]  [ 6]

Comment: Can you post smaller images, or one containing both? It's very hard to compare them as I have to scroll up and down.

Comment: @Mordechai done. You can just put 'm' for medium at the end of the imgur code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Partial solution:

> The images can be divided such that line segments can be grouped to represent a (possibly rotated) number that would appear on a digital clock. Each line segment must be used once.
>  The image also contains at least one of each numeric digit. 
>  Then, you group adjacent numbers together and take their sums. Reading the sums clockwise will get you the sequence in the proper order.
>  A:
>  [image: image A]
>  We have [?], 10 (1+9), 11 (8+3), 9 (2+7), 11 (6+5).
>  So the unknown must be 4+0 = **4**.
>  B: In progress. My strategy may be wrong because I can't find a solution. There are 4 locations that could be the "0", and all of them result in line segments that aren't numeric.

Comment: *all the 10 digits..0 to 9

Comment: That's actually B-

Comment: @TSLF I figured that was a typo because the negative sign is not a digit.

Comment: @ Mike @But that's how else can 2 digits stick with each other in 2 layers

Comment: A: 5pairs that sticks at 2points are added..   B- 5pairs that sticks on 1 segment are subtracted.